# Map $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that every 2-set is a neighbor exactly once

Tags: co.combinatorics, infinite-combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

Is there a map $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ with $a\neq b$ there is exactly one $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\{a,b\} = \{f(n),f(n+1)\}$?

Comment: You are asking for an Euler tour of the countable complete graph.  This should be doable with a random walk, as every node has infinite degree.  Just remember to go back to every place you ever visited again and again.  If you want a guarantee, consider completing a tour of K2n+1, and extend that to a tour of K2n+3.  Gerhard "Take Lots Of Pocket Money" Paseman, 2020.08.03.

Comment: How about defining $f$ by induction? $f(0)=0$ and $f(n+1)=$ the smallest $k$ such that $\{f(n),k\}\neq\{f(m),f(m+1)\}$ for all $m<n$.

Comment: I think that is what I just said.  ;) (Near equivalence left to the reader to demonstrate.)  Upon reflection, that gives a different tour.  Perhaps our walkers will meet? Gerhard "Using Different Words, Of Course" Paseman, 2020.08.03.

Comment: Aaron Meyerowitz's answer shows that my previous comment doesn't work. I'd delete it, but then what other people have written, referring to it, would no longer make sense. So I'll leave it up, but I hereby warn people not to rely on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure that the descriptions so far work. They seem to result in things like

$ 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 0, 5, 1, 6, 0, 7, 1, 8, 0, 9, 1, 10,\cdots$

Here is something that works.

[image]

The sequence starts $0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 0, 5, 4, 6, 5, 3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 6$ so the pairs visited are

$ (0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4), (1, 3), (1, 4), (0, 4), (0, 5), $

$(4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6), (3, 5), (3, 6), (2, 6), (2, 5), (1, 5), (1, 6), (0, 6), (0, 7), (6, 7)$

The rule  is that, after determining  $f(1),\ldots, f(n)$, set $f(n+1)$ so that  $\lbrace f(n),f(n+1)\rbrace $ is the least possible pair not yet used where the order is $\lbrace a,b \rbrace < \lbrace c,d \rbrace$  if $\max(a,b) <\max(c,d)$ and, for $a=\max(a,b,c),$ we have $\lbrace a,b \rbrace < \lbrace a,c \rbrace$  if $|a-b|<|a-c|$ or $|a-b|=|a-c$ and $b<c.$

Comment: I found a graphic representation helped. Just subtracting edges, one finds K_2n+1 - K_2n-1 is an edge shared by 2n-1 triangles, and has an Euler circuit.  So one can progress along these differences to provide an Euler circuit for an arbitrarily large finite complete graph with an odd number of vertices.  Gerhard "The Differences Are All Planar" Paseman, 2020.08.03.